# Этимология слова "Москва"

Tags: этимология, топонимика

Что изначально означало слово "Москва"?

Comment: не знаю, правда или нет , но слово "москва" наши предки использовали как и слово "ура"

Comment: Однажды простой финский парень Эксель встретил на берегу реки незнакомую девушку. "Как зовут тебя, красавица, и что ты здесь делаешь?" - спросил юноша. "Мое имя Моксель, я помогаю отцу ловить рыбу" - тихо ответила девушка и покрепче ухватила свое большое весло. Кто их, парней, знает, что придет им в голову через минуту...
![Та самая Моксель](http://burnovoding.ru/uploads/images/7/3/6/9/441/129f7a7bbd.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть множество гипотез на этот счет, но самая распространенная - это родство слова "москва" и "промозглый", то есть, холодны сырой. То есть, слово "москва" обозначает низменность, сырое место.

Answer (score 3):

Возражу. Предложенная Г. А. Ильинским связь с "промозглостью" совершенно неубедительна, из серии народной этимологии.
Есть, правда, не очень популярная ныне гипотеза академика Топорова, тоже использующая балто-славянскую версию, но основу автор возводит не к "мозглости", а к "слякотности", "жидкости" (в этом же ряду оказыватся "мозг").

А вообще угро-финские версии никто не отменял. Единственный их недостаток - отсутствие общеугрофинского корня, подходящего на роль прародителя названия. В разных угро-финских языках можно найти разные соответствия.

Всё сказанное - пересказ небольшой части из содержательнейшей и интереснейшей статьи на эту тему профессора М. В. Горбаневского.
http://moscow.gramota.ru/znan01.shtml

Answer (score 2):

Фантазия Сигизмунда Кржижановского:

...Настал последний день. Поезд мой отходил в шесть с минутами. На небе сияло полуденное июльское солнце: в моем распоряжении было несколько часов, - и я решил их отдать прощанию с Москвой. Неторопливым шагом дошел я до одного из мостов, переброшенных через реку, и, свесившись с перил, в последний раз наблюдал волны и пену, уносимые быстрым, как время, течением. 
С илистых берегов доносилось протяжное кваканье лягушек, в последний раз напоминавшее мне предание о том, как строился этот удивительный город (начало предания вы можете прочесть у известного русского историка Забелина) в далеком прошлом, когда вместо домов тут были кочки, вместо площадей затянутые тиной болота, вместо людей лягушки, пришел неведомо откуда царевич Мос и посватался неведомо зачем к царевне Ква. 
Построили среди болот и топей брачные хоромы и отпраздновали свадьбу. Но как только Мос и Ква остались одни, слышит Ква - кто-то зовет ее по имени. 
"Пойди, - говорит она мужу, которому бы к жене, а не от жены, - посмотри, кто меня зовет?" 
Досадно Мосу, но вышел, смотрит - на кочке жаба и кваква. Прогнал Мос жабу, но только вернулся к жене, а уж с другой кочки опять ее кто-то по имени. 
И снова жена: "Пойди - узнай". 
Обозлился Мос и велел построить брачные хоромы в другом месте. Но и там, чуть остался с молодой женой, отовсюду и со всех кочек зовут царицу Ква по имени, от мужа отрывают. Заплакала царица Ква и просит построить дом в третьем месте. А там и в четвертом, и в пятом, и в тридцать третьем. Стучат топоры, растут дом за домом и дом к дому; и где- были кочки - там кровля, где озера - там площади; где топи и болота с квакающими лягушками - там большой город с людьми, говорящими на чистом акающем диалекте чистейшего русского языка. 
И теперь уже никто не мог помешать тому, чтоб Мос и Ква наконец соединились даже именами: "Москва".

("Возвращение Мюнхгаузена")

Comment: Раздел юмор. Оценил.

Answer (score 0):

Действительно, топоним Москва можно вывести из финно-угорских корней. Одну из таких версий можно посмотреть по [ссылке](http://books.google.ru/books?id=4-sr05ligyEC&lpg=PA149&ots=AqnBS53aVY&dq=%D0%BC.%D0%B3.%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0&hl=ru&pg=PA149#v=onepage&q=%D0%BC.%D0%B3.%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0&f=false)

Comment: Автор крепко ерундит по крайней мере в части причин перехода Москы в Москва. Остальное просто не очень внимательно читал, ибо ничего нового). 

Но по части ква(ковь)<кы, то он объясняется совсем не влиянием формы "Москылва" (а была ли она вообще?), а общефонетическим явлением утраты качества Ы после заднеязычных. Кы в абсолютном конце слова было вообще весьма распостранено и породило рефлексы ква и ковь (при не очень понятном принципе что - когда).

Answer (score 0):

Зачем гадать на кофейной гуще . Не логичнее ли открыть древнерусский источник "Киевский синопсис" от 1674 года и прочесть первоначальную  историческую версию происхождения топонима МОСКВА .

> О МОСОХА, ПРАРОДИТЕЛЯ СЛОВ'ЯНОРÓССІЙСЬКОГО, И О ПЛЕМЕНИ ЕГО .                                                                                                                                                        Мосох, шестой сын Афетів, внук Ноев, [имя его] переводится с еврейского на славянский как "вытягивает" или "тот, кто растаскивает" от лука, что напинається, и распространение от великих и многочисленных народов московских славенорóссійських - польских, волынских, чешских, больгарських, сербских, карвацьких  и вообще всех, сколько их есть, естественно использует славянский язык. Ибо Мосох по потопе года 131 уйдя из Вавилона с племенем своим, скоро в Азии и Европе, над берегами Понтийского или Черного моря народы московитов во имя свое расселил. И оттуда умножился народ, расселяясь день от дня в северные земли за Черное море, над Доном и Волгою реками, и над озером или заливом морской Меотис 386, куда Дон впадает, в степях широко поселениями своими розпоширилися, согласно особенности и витлумаченню имени прародителя своего Мосоха, ибо если Афет переводится как "Расширение" или "Расширенный", подобно тому значит и Мосох - "растаскивает" и "далеко вытягивает". И так от Мосоха, праотца Славенорóссійського, от наследства его, не только Москва  - народ великий, но и вся Русь или Рóссія вышеназванная пошли, хотя в определенных землях несколько в славянах и изменились, однако единственной славянском языке говорят.О НАЗВАНИИ МОСКВЫ - НАРОДА И ЦАРСТВЕННОГО ГРАДА .Название и - "москва" - происходит от имени праотца Мосоха, которое издревле было известно древним летописцам, однако немало и молчали [о нем]: потому что когда трое братьев, князей варяжских, о которых будет писаться ниже, и великая княгиня Ольга, Елена, и всея Рóссії первый самодержец Владимир, и второй - Мономах, Рóссією владели, тогда рóссами или русаками звались, а в Рóссійських землях только Киевские, Владимирские, Великоновгородські, Черниговские, Галицкие, Словенские и другие князья именитыми были. Москва ибо над рекой Москвой - от ее имени назван. Сначала из дерева построен был, и незначительный, вплоть до великого князя Иоанна Даниловича, который престол княжения с Володимираграда в Москву-град перенес .

Обратим внимание и на то , как пишется название Москва по-гречески :  **μόσχα** - звучит , как **МОСХА** , без окончания -ВА. Церковнославянское имя МОСОХ в ивритном оригинале **משך**  по-буквенно прочитывается (иврит читается справа-налево) , как **МОСХ** (при этом , **Х** может переходить в **К** , т.к. обозначена буквой **ך** каф софит ) , -  т.е. греческий вариант топонима МОСКВА соответствует первоисходной ивритной форме имени МОСОХ . А -ВА это уже окончание типа , как Полта-***ва*** , Красла-***ва***(город в Латвии) , Братисла-***ва***(Словакия) , Наепряд-***ва***(река в верховьях Дона) и т.п. .

Comment: mosquito=mosqow-  мошков(о-а)-москва

Answer (score -1):

Москва - город с большим количеством церквей, возможно в то время и мечетей. Архитектура их в любом случае схожа и с полумесяцем под крестом. Так что логично предположить, мечеть mosque -> Moscú Москва

Comment: Боже... Какие еще мечети в граде Кучковом? Текст ваш исправил, чтобы хоть как-то читалось без головоломки.

Answer (score -2):

МАСКА?МА-материя;С КА-дух,душа.То есть материя с душой-Это живой человек,или жизнь!МАСКА-МАСКОВИЯ-МАСКВА!Правильно писать название нашей столицы МАСКВА!!!Вот профес.Чудинов прочитал на карте гипербореи МАРА,МАСКА,КРУМИЯ.Мара(шмара)-богиня смерти;МАСКА-это жизнь;КРУМИЯ-это мечта рода,или мечта возрождения(мия,мрия это мечта).!РУсь,РУский,РУмын(даки),РУсин,РУги( были на балтики)...это вот РУ-это кРУг жизни,и имеет ведическое происхождениеИ обоснованно на поверьи,что человеку дано несколько кРУгов жизни,что бы пройти земное чистилише,и полноценно взрастить душу(а не тело).Так же как например слова РУка,РУсло...РУсло реки(вообще то жыла)-это вода,выпавшая в виде осадков на землю и стёкшая в море,озеро,опять испарившись....И так по кРУгу!РУка(вообще то длань)-указывает земной жизненный путь,направление в жизни души!А заяц РУсак?Почему нету зайца украинца или поляка,чеха...?Дело в том,что заяц бегает всегда по кРУгу,путая следы.